# unexpected date format is coming like this /Date(1486495036000)/ in table

Tags: sql-server, ajax, model-view-controller, ado.net

i'm inserting time in the data base and fetching the datetime from the database. while inserting value its inserting like this "2017-04-11 02:09:00.000" but while showing in table its showing like this /Date(1486495036000)/.

code

```
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into sms values('" + today + "','" + usecase + "','" + smsdata + "')", con);
```

database sample data

```
updtd_date               usecase    id  sms
2017-04-11 02:09:00.000  watertank  1   Tank filled
```

data type of updtd_date in table
smalldatetime

controller

```
 public ActionResult getSMS()
        {
            using (dbEntities dc = new dbEntities())
            {
                var data = dc.sms.OrderByDescending(a => a.id).ToList();
                return Json(new { data=data }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
```

view

```
  <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#myTable').DataTable({
                "ajax": {
                    "url": "/WaterLevel/getSMS",
                    "type": "GET",
                    "datatype": "json"
                },
                "columns": [
                    { "data": "updtd_date", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data": "usecase", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data": "id", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data": "sms", "autoWidth": true }

                ]
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parse date .

if you are using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/use-it/browser/) then you can parse it like.

```
 var date = "\/Date(1486495036000)\/";
 nowDate = new Date(parseInt(date.substr(6)));
 var result = nowDate.format("ddd mmm dd yyyy HH:MM:ss");
```

Use [Render function](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) to format column value.